# Python http.server .path returning / rather than protocol://netloc/path#fragment

Tags: python-3.x, http, urllib

Python 3.8 am working with a simple http server and am expecting self.path to give me the whole url as every urllib.parse example I can find take self.path and breaks it into its respective parts, however, all I'm getting is '/'.

TBH I realise I've probably got the wrong end of the stick but I've reached the stage where I have nowhere else to turn.

Here's an simplified server I was expecting to output something like "http://localhost:8000#test" but all I get is "/"

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        outstr=self.path
        self.wfile.write(bytes(outstr,'utf8'))

httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 8000), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What happens if you input your local IP address where it says "localhost"?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and it is becuase the browser does not send the fragment (i.e. the #test) to the server.
The http://localhost:8000/ isn't included because this is the server root.
For anyone who had the same problem as me, I included this javascript in the html response to redirect the user back to the server while converting the fragment into a query (which is sent to the server).

```html
<script>let url = window.location.href.replace("#","?");window.location.replace(url);</script>
```